# Hive and schema evolution

Tags: cassandra, hive, hbase

We have a requirement where we want to create a user profile data. This profile data/schema would keep on evolving meaning over time more and more attributes will be added to the profile. Some data could be deleted, updated, and extended.

I want to know if Hive+Avro is a good store for such usecase (I presume hive is not schema-less and does not support schema evolution - better suited for data that is immutable). Would HBase/Cassandra be a good choice?

Answer (score 0):

Schema evolution with Hive/Avro is quite possible - a good explanation can be found [here](http://getindata.com/schema-evolution-with-avro-and-hive/), however it looks like currently it does not support ACID insert/update/deletes on Avro dataset( ORC file format is supported though) Also HBase/Cassandra can be used for this use case. Major differentiation between these technologies would be what you do with the evolving data ( read/write performance, underlying storage, CAP properties, underlying framework (map-reduce or native) for data query summarization etc.) plus other specific feature offered by each of these technologies. You can check a side by side comparison between these three [here](https://db-engines.com/en/system/Cassandra%3BHBase%3BHive)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have question regarding updates and deletes of existing records. For example, in the above link lets say for "natalia" I want to change country to "Italy" and want to delete record for "tofi", can I do this through Hive? Does this go and change in the Avro file? Since Avro file is immutable (as it is in HDFS), does it create a new Avro file?

I understand how this (deletion/updates) work in HBase (which automatically takes care of this by maintaining different HFile (immutable) and then does minor/major compaction to keep only the latest version of data)

Comment: If I am getting you right - I think Hive does not support transactional insert/update/deletes on Avro format yet, seems it is currently supported for ORC file format only. So that will rule out Avro in your use case.

Comment: Then does ORC file format support schema evolution i.e. adding new columns on the fly for new or existing records? I need all these supports insert/update/delete/extending-schema for new or existing records. Do you think HBase/Cassandra will be a better choice?

Comment: I have not worked on evolving schemas in ORC format but a quick look at JIRA (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ORC-54) suggest that they have lately added this support but may be not as extensive as you may want. In case of Hbase/Cassadra, the data can be visualized as a sorted map of map where the inner keys are the column names so you can add or remove columns in new data. But why would you want to change the schema of old data. Typically the data and schema goes hand in hand and you do not need to change schema once a piece of data is inserted.

Comment: As I said I am building a profile store where new attributes will keep on adding to the profile (attribute values could be nested structures). It is possible that for some existing record with some unique id, I may update value of one of the attribute and/or add new column.

Comment: Then I think Hbase can be useful especially given it's native integration with hadoop hdfs. But then you should carefully investigate on the kind access pattern you would need and plan the evolving schema accordingly. Cassandra is quite good at simple key lookups but not on range based queries.

Comment: Thank you for response. What you said makes sense as Hbase's schema-less nature makes schema evolution easy but has to be done carefully. I was wondering if schema less is same as schema evolution? Also have u seen any use-case where avro is used (lets say avro schema or version stored as one of the field) to figure out tables row schema?